# Как можно улучшить код обработки данных?

Tags: python, pandas, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Есть набор данных с 3 колонками : `REV_NUM_CL`, `ID_COMMS`, ,`DT_CONTACT`.

Надо выбрать только те данные (значения: `REV_NUM_CL`, `ID_COMMS`), которые удовлетворяют любому из условий:

1. В группировке по `REV_NUM_CL` есть только один `ID_COMMS` с заполненными `DT_CONTACT`.
2. В группировке по `REV_NUM_CL` есть только один уникальный `ID_COMMS`.

Общая цель в том, чтобы найти для каждого `REV_NUM_CL` найти уникальный `ID_COMMS`, если это возможно.

Я смог решить эту задачу, однако мое решение кажется мне далеким от идеального.
Думаю, можно проще, короче и понятнее. Помогите упростить.

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [    
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 1, 'ID_COMMS': 11, 'DT_CONTACT': 111},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 1, 'ID_COMMS': 12, 'DT_CONTACT': 122},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 2, 'ID_COMMS': 21, 'DT_CONTACT': None},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 2, 'ID_COMMS': 22, 'DT_CONTACT': None},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 3, 'ID_COMMS': 31, 'DT_CONTACT': 311},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 3, 'ID_COMMS': 32, 'DT_CONTACT': 321},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 3, 'ID_COMMS': 33, 'DT_CONTACT': 331},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 3, 'ID_COMMS': 33, 'DT_CONTACT': 332},    
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 3, 'ID_COMMS': 34, 'DT_CONTACT': None},        
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 4, 'ID_COMMS': None, 'DT_CONTACT': None},
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 5, 'ID_COMMS': 51, 'DT_CONTACT': 511},    
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 5, 'ID_COMMS': 52, 'DT_CONTACT': None},  
    {'REV_NUM_CL': 6, 'ID_COMMS': 61, 'DT_CONTACT': None}    
]

# Группа 1 не подходит, т.к. есть два разных ID_COMMS и у обоих заполнен DT_CONTACT
# Группа 2 не подходит, т.к есть два разных ID_COMMS и у обоих не заполнен DT_CONTACT
# Группа 3 не подходит, так как есть больше одного ID_COMMS и которых заполнен DT_CONTACT
# Группа 4 не подходит, т.к. ID_COMMS нет вообще
# Группа 5 подходит, так как есть только один ID_COMMS у которго заполнен DT_CONTACT
# Группа 6 подходит, так как есть всего один ID_COMMS

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Посчитать уникальное значение ID_COMMS, где заполнен DT_CONTACT в группах
df_cnt = df[df['DT_CONTACT'].notnull()].groupby('REV_NUM_CL')[['ID_COMMS']].nunique()
df_cnt.columns = ['CNT']

# Посчитать уникальное значение ID_COMMS, вообще
df_cnt_u = df.groupby('REV_NUM_CL')[['ID_COMMS']].nunique()
df_cnt_u.columns = ['CNT_U']

# И объединить в массив обратно
df = pd.merge(df, df_cnt, on='REV_NUM_CL', how='left')
df['CNT'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(df, df_cnt_u, on='REV_NUM_CL', how='left')
df['CNT_U'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df['FIRST'] = ( ( df['CNT'] == 1 ) 
               & ( df['DT_CONTACT'].notnull() ) 
               & ( df['ID_COMMS'].notnull() )
              ).astype(int)
df['SECOND'] = ( ( df['CNT_U'] == 1 )
                & ( df['ID_COMMS'].notnull() )
               ).astype(int)
# Итог:
df_res = df[(df['FIRST'] == 1) | (df['SECOND'] == 1) ][['ID_COMMS', 'REV_NUM_CL']].drop_duplicates() # перестраховался
```

Comment: можете пояснить почему строка с индексом `11` - __не__ выбрана в результирующей выборке - она удовлетворяет обоим условиям?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что речь о строке `{'REV_NUM_CL': 5, 'ID_COMMS': 52, 'DT_CONTACT': None}`  ?
Она не попадает в результат, т.к. не удовлетворяет условию 2, ID_COMMS не уникальный для REV_NUM_CL.

Comment: Обновли вопрос, т.к. понял, что плохо описал задачу.

Comment: тогда по вашей логике и 10-я строка не должна попадать в результат, т.к. принадлежит той же группе, что и 11я

Comment: А 10 попадает под первое условие, еще раз обновил описание. Мой код вроде делает как раз то, что мне надо

Comment: "красивое" решение не получается потому, что нет единства внутри одной группы - на примере 10й и 11й строки - вы выбираете __половину__ группы

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!